# Css taking the icon bottom

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am new at css can you please help me,i want to take the icon at the same line with Text its now a bit higher than text.(taking the icon around 2px bottom)[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to both text and icon elements;